# Android HttpURLConnection - ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)

Tags: android

Ola,

Estou com um problema que muitos já tiveram quando desenvolvem código para conexão com a internet no android:

```
java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
```

O código que criei é exatamente igual ao sugerido pelo Google no Android Developer:

http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Note que já inclui as propriedades:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
```

e também o:

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
```

Estava funcionando muito bem, mas agora parou em alguns dispositivos.
Isso que é estranho. Tenho muitos usuários que não estao tendo problema algum, mas alguns outros usuários (que estão com a mesma versão do APP) estão tendo este problema. Começou no dia 26/12, sem nenhuma explicação. Afeta tanto GET quanto o POST.
Estou tendo este erro no Galaxy-Y - JellyBean (4.1.2).

Alguem tem alguma outra sugestão?

Comment: Qual é o erro que ocorre?

Comment: Da uma olhada nessa resposta, eu já vi esse erro e pelo que sei não é do código não. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21319789/3517631